# Free chat plugin

Tags: plugin-recommendation

Is there a WordPress plugin that allows users to have a private chat with an admin but that there is no need for a payment plan (like you have with support sites such as OGG or 123flashchat).

I  just want a simple chat box that tells users whether I'm online or not and lets them contact me through it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I know exactly what you need: LiveAgent - http://www.qualityunit.com/liveagent/

You can register free chat account which allows you to chat with your customers directly as they browse your pages.

All you need to do is to use this plugin:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/liveagent/

and it'll create your free account and integrate chat button in to your pages automatically.